# Downsampling majority class of binary labelled graph

Tags: classification, sampling, graph-theory

I have a graph of user-to-user interactions, where the vertices (users) are given a binary label. I want to generate a downsample of the majority class (and keep all of the vertices in the minority class), such that the vertices that would connect the users that are downsampled away to the rest of my graph are as few as possible (as I think there's decent signal encoded in the connections between users and I'd like to retain as many as I can naturally, in my downsampled data).

I'm struggling to find a way to do this that's not computationally ridiculous - is there an existing algorithm or method that I can adapt to this use case that anyone is aware of?